# How to find longitude and latitude when using GMSAutocompleteFetcherDelegate in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

According to Place Autocomplete documentation objects of predictions array don't have location info.
So how should i get the details of longitude and latitude.
Below is my code -

```
extension ViewController: GMSAutocompleteFetcherDelegate {


func didAutocomplete(with predictions: [GMSAutocompletePrediction]) {

    tableData.removeAll()

    for prediction in predictions{

        tableData.append(prediction.attributedFullText.string)

    }
    locationTable.reloadData()
}

func didFailAutocompleteWithError(_ error: Error) {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Comment: I have no idea what `GMSAutocompleteFetcher` is. You should explain, and perhaps add the relevant tag to your question.

Comment: See the following answer i have added.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the following method inside `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` of your table view. So you will get latitude, latitude and address.

> I have used it personally and tested it works 100%.

Some syntax may change depending on your swift version.

```
import GoogleMaps

func getLatLongFromAutocompletePrediction(prediction:GMSAutocompletePrediction){

    let placeClient = GMSPlacesClient()

    placeClient.lookUpPlaceID(prediction.placeID!) { (place, error) -> Void in
        if let error = error {
             //show error
            return
        }

        if let place = place {
            place.coordinate.longitude //longitude 
            place.coordinate.latitude //latitude
            obj.attributedFullText.string //Address in string
        } else {
            //show error
        }
    }
}
```

Feel free to ask anything if required.

Comment: Always Welcome.

Comment: Thanks, this method is saviour for me.

Answer (score -2):

I recommand you to use CoreLocation to get location in latitude and longitude :

```
import CoreLocation
class YourViewController 
{

let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
var locValue: CLLocationCoordinate2D! = nil


    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Ask for Authorisation from the User.
    self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()

    // For use in foreground
    self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    }


    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
}
```

And here is the delegate

```
//MARK: - Location and alternative stuff

extension YourViewController : CLLocationManagerDelegate {

// MARK: Save actual position
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let locValue:CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location!.coordinate
    self.locValue = locValue
    }
}
```

Comment: your recommendation is honest, but not good, because, I was using this thing in live app, and I get very serious trouble using this, because apple does not provide the correct lat/lng from the google address. If we get the address from google and get the lat/lng from apple, than our location will be far from home.